# Why remix account is empty when select "Injected Web3"?

Tags: remix

Why remix account is empty when select "Injected Web3"?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Remix inside Metamask?  If so, you need to explicitly allow Remix to access Metamask accounts.  This could be done in Metamask settings.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is not being read is because this version of Metamask [enables privacy mode by default](https://medium.com/metamask/introducing-privacy-mode-42549d4870fa). What this does is require you to approve the application to view/use your wallets on Metamask.

For your specific issue, you have not yet approved Remix to use your accounts, therefore it cannot read your addresses, as you are seeing. To fix this, enable privacy mode by going the the Metamask settings and scrolling to the bottom.

Remix does not ask for permission to use the wallets like most Dapps do, therefore you must enable it in the settings, as opposed to approving the pop-up that you see on the tutorial.